# How to store optical data in InfluxDB

Tags: time-series, influxdb

I am new to InfluxDB and having doubts about how to store my data. We have an output from our optical sensors that are thousands values per timestamp. So far I've seen examples only for few values per timestamp.
My data would be something like this:

timestamp, tags{}, fields{value1, value2... value10000}

Is there a best practice to store data like this in InfluxDB? Also, is there a limit for how many fields one data point can have?

Comment: Please provide details about sensor data with example. Also clarify how many records per second and types of queries or analysis.  A customized data storage system may work better.

Comment: @JasonLivesay, an example of data would be something like this:

2016-11-15T16:43:40.305464, -13.12, -9.40, 0.55, -5.25, -1.35, -0.24, -3.28, ...

Every record may contain about 10K values. And we are expecting to have 10 records per second for each sensor. Regarding types of queries or analysis I'm not sure as it will be done by data scientist. But I know we have to store raw data and query it.

Comment: 10k * 2  bytes * 10 = 200kb per second * 3600 = 720 mb per hour * 24 = 17 gb per day.  I would talk to data scientist find out what types of analysis he is doing and then look into filtering and compressing the data on that basis first in context of your preferred db then if that fails with whatever seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact relationship between the sensors and their data, here are 3 potential options.

**Case 1: Time Sequential Data**

It's worth noting that InfluxDB is able to use timestamps down to nanosecond precision. If your thousands of values are sequential and can be individually timestamped, consider writing/storing them in individual timestamps

```
INSERT measurement sensor=[value1] 2016-11-26T00:00:00.00000000Z
INSERT measurement sensor=[value2] 2016-11-26T00:00:00.00010000Z
...
INSERT measurement sensor=[value10000] 2016-11-26T00:00:01.00000000Z
```

This has the advantage of allowing all your measurements to be seen in one time series.

**Case 2: One-to-one mapping sensor to value**

If each value comes from a unique sensor such that you have thousands of points and thousands of sensors, consider making a tag or field for each sensor.

A: Tagging values by sensor

```
INSERT measurement,sensor=sensor1 field=[value1] 2016-11-26T00:00:00Z
INSERT measurement,sensor=sensor2 field=[value2] 2016-11-26T00:00:00Z
...
INSERT measurement,sensor=sensor10000 field=[value10000] 2016-11-26T00:00:00Z
```

B: Each sensor is a field

```
INSERT measurement sensor1=[value1] sensor2=[value2] ... sensor10000=[value10000]
```

If there are multiple metrics coming from each sensor I would consider option A. If each sensor only produces 1 metric, I would choose option B.

**Case 3: Variable number of values**

If you have a variable number of values per timestamp, for example, in machine vision where you've thresholded and extracted an object from an image, you are hitting the limits of a TSDB. Spatial data like this does not map well into a metric oriented based time series database like InfluxDB.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm afraid case 1 and case 2 don't apply here as we have one optical sensor that at particular timestamp outputs thousands of readings. In my case it would be case 3 (you have a typo there). Do you have any suggestions in terms what kind of database we could use?

Comment: I agree with @JasonLivestay and his response. What type of analysis are you doing on this data? Do you need lossless storage? If the data can be represented as an image and you're doing some form of image analysis, I'd suggest saving as JPEG and using your os file system.

Comment: Also, if you think my post answers your orginial question, please mark it as an answer. Thanks!